# Como mover uma janela utilizando um botão? c#

Tags: c#, windows, wpf

Eu tenho uma aplicação em WPF que não tem bordas nem fundo, é só um botão estilizado com uma imagem e um frame, porém eu gostaria que fosse possível movê-la.
Meu código atual está assim:

```
    <Button Name="button" Margin="10,130.475,377.541,10" Click="button_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Rectangle Width="Auto" Margin="29.78,15.35,20.479,13.896" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stroke="{x:Null}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="img.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
//<...>
```

Tentei desta forma, mas não obtive resultados

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DragMove();
            //<...>
        }
```

Edit:
Seguindo as respostas, adequei este código à aplicação, porém a movimentação só ocorre com o mouse direito e o esquerdo não gera nenhum evento.

```
private bool clicked = false;
private Point lmAbs = new Point();
void PnMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    clicked = true;
    this.lmAbs = e.GetPosition(this);
    this.lmAbs.Y = Convert.ToInt16(this.Top) + this.lmAbs.Y;
    this.lmAbs.X = Convert.ToInt16(this.Left) + this.lmAbs.X;
}

void PnMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    clicked = false;
}

void PnMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (clicked)
    {
        Point MousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
        Point MousePositionAbs = new Point();
        MousePositionAbs.X = Convert.ToInt16(this.Left) + MousePosition.X;
        MousePositionAbs.Y = Convert.ToInt16(this.Top) + MousePosition.Y;
        this.Left = this.Left + (MousePositionAbs.X - this.lmAbs.X);
        this.Top = this.Top + (MousePositionAbs.Y - this.lmAbs.Y);
        this.lmAbs = MousePositionAbs;
    }
}
```

Uma forma de fazer com que eu consiga pegar o evento do mouse esquerdo, foi utilizando o *PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown*, mas nesse caso a janela fica presa ao cursor e não consigo soltá-la.

Comment: use o evento onmousedown e onmouseup associado ao botão que você quer, e o evento onmousemove associado na sua tela, no down, marca uma flag como true, no up, marca como false, no move, se a flag é true, move a tela junto com o mouse

Answer (score 1):

Há uma técnica disponível [neste projeto](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11114/Move-window-form-without-Titlebar-in-C) do CodeProject, ela é mais ou menos assim:

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Isso faz exatamente o que o Windows move quando clica no título da janela e arrasta ela. Não é bem pelo botão, mas você clica e arrasta a janela usando o mouse e clicando na janela mesmo, não no botão.

Mas se você realmente quer fazer por um botão, teria que associar eventos do mouse à ele:

```
private bool mouseDown;
private Point lastLocation;

private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    lastLocation = e.Location;
}

private void button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(mouseDown)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(
            (this.Location.X - lastLocation.X) + e.X, (this.Location.Y - lastLocation.Y) + e.Y);

        this.Update();
    }
}

private void button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma ele me retorna _"CS0123 No overload for 'button_MouseUp' matches delegate 'MouseButtonEventHandler'"_, assim como MouseDown e MouseMove.